# Query to get column name and value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table that looks like this:

```
emplid      year        JAN     FEB     MAR     APR     MAY
------      ----        ---     ---     ---     ---     ---
1234        2018         x       x       x     Retire
5678        2018         x   Terminated
9876        2018         x       x       x       x    Transfer
5432        2018         x       x       x       x       x
```

and I want to return a table that looks like this:

```
emplid      year        month       Reason
------      ----        -----       ------
1234        2018         APR        Retire
5678        2018         FEB        Terminated
9876        2018         MAY        Transfer
```

Basically I want to find the year and month that an employee retired, quit, was terminated, etc, plus what that reason was.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?  I am using ms sql server.  If you need any other information, just let me know.  I can't figure out how to do it.  Way over my level of expertise.  Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that you've not followed normal form with your table design; really your table should have been designed in the way that you want your expected output. Hopefully the reason for your question is because that is your goal (if it isn't, it should be). I note that some rows have `'x'`'s in, and others blank. Do you *really* have those `'x'`'s in your data..?

Comment: wtf is that structure

Comment: It is very complicated, that is wtf it is.  There is way more to it than just this.  I simplified it down to make it easier to digest.  Like i said I am no expert.

Comment: they arent x's in the actual table.  They are other values like PA, 2C, etc etc.  There are blanks as well.  The table basically tracks what department some one is in over the months until they retire, quite, etc.  So once they do that, the rest of the row is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/78e659/18/0)

```
select t1.emplid,t1.year,
(
  CASE 
    WHEN t1.JAN <> 'x' AND t1.JAN <> '' THEN 'JAN'
    WHEN t1.FEB <> 'x' AND  t1.FEB <> '' THEN 'FEB'
    WHEN t1.MAR <> 'x' AND  t1.MAR <> '' THEN 'MAR'
    WHEN t1.APR <> 'x' AND  t1.APR <> '' THEN 'APR'
    WHEN t1.MAY <> 'x' AND  t1.MAY <> '' THEN 'MAY'
  end
)  as month,
(
  CASE 
    WHEN t1.JAN <> 'x' AND t1.JAN <> '' THEN t1.JAN
    WHEN t1.FEB <> 'x' AND  t1.FEB <> '' THEN t1.FEB
    WHEN t1.MAR <> 'x' AND  t1.MAR <> '' THEN t1.MAR
    WHEN t1.APR <> 'x' AND  t1.APR <> '' THEN t1.APR
    WHEN t1.MAY <> 'x' AND  t1.MAY <> '' THEN t1.MAY 
  end
)  as Reason
 from table1 t1
 where Reason  is not null
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a very handy place to use `APPLY`:

```
select t.empid, t.year, v.mon, v.reason
from t cross apply
     (values ('JAN', jan), ('FEB', feb), ('MAR', mar), ('APR', apr), ('MAY', may)
     ) v(mon, reason)
where reason <> 'x';
```

Answer (score 2):

Extend below query for rest of months from JUN to DEC

```
SELECT emplid,year,
CASE WHEN JAN <> 'x' THEN 'JAN' 
     WHEN FEB <> 'x' THEN 'FEB'
     WHEN MAR <> 'x' THEN 'MAR'
     WHEN APR <> 'x' THEN 'APR'
     WHEN MAY <> 'x' THEN 'MAY'

--Rest of months
END [month],
REPLACE(JAN+FEB+MAR+APR+MAY,'x','') Reason
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table is just not normalized however...
you can use:

```
select emplid, year, 
case 
when not (JAN = 'x')
  then 'JAN'
when not (FEB = 'x')
  then 'FEB'
as month
```

and the same for the reason.

Comment: I know it isnt normalized, but for the purpose I am using it, I dont think I can normalize it.  Ill look into it thought, thank you.